# Cortana integration for multiple Phrase Topics

Tags: javascript, windows, uwp, cortana, vcd

I'm creating a Javascript UWP for Windows 10.
I have integrated Cortana, and everything works fine except one command, which needs two Phrase Topics.

Example: Get Directions from Source to Destination.

My VCD file is like this:

```
<Command Name="getDirections">
    <Example>MyApp get directions from New York to New Jersey</Example>
    <ListenFor>get directions from {source} to {destination}</ListenFor>
    <Feedback>Fetching directions from {source} to {destination}</Feedback>
    <VoiceCommandService Target="myBackgroundService"/>
</Command>

<PhraseTopic Label="source" Scenario="Natural Language">
      <Subject> Natural Language </Subject>
</PhraseTopic>

<PhraseTopic Label="destination" Scenario="Natural Language">
      <Subject> Natural Language </Subject>
</PhraseTopic>
```

**But the problem is, If I create 2 Phrase topics inside my command set, then Cortana commands fails to install from VCD file (The function call to install voice commands from VCD fails).**

Is there any way to use one phrase topic at two places in same listen command.

Please help me out :)

Comment: By "Cortana commands fails to install" do you mean the app failed to install? Or you mean the Cortana didn't start your app?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT No, app works correctly. Only the function call to install voice commands from VCD file fails. I think, only one phrase Topic is allowed per command set. But there should be some workaround, for using one phrase topic at two places.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Since, Commands are not being installed. Cortana can no longer activate my app.

Comment: I made a demo but didn't reproduce this problem, could you please check if there are tags, which have the same `Label` inside a  `Commandset`? If there is no such tag, could you please share a basic demo?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Thanks for trying it out. There are no duplicate labels. Let me try a basic demo. I will get back to you!

Comment: I used the official [VoiceCommandSample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand). Pasted your VCD codes into the VCD file and delete one destination tag(there is already one there), change the `Natural Language` to any city. Run the app. Then close it.  Try cortana with `AdventureWorks get directions from city1 to city2`. The app start correctly.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Bingo! I couldn't rectify what was the problem really. But, I recreated the VCD file. And soon after commands started to register successfully. Other commands worked fine, while this particular command did not work.

After restarting computer, it worked like a charm :)

Thanks for your help!